# libGDX MENU button

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a game, in which are some function buttons, which defined as `ImageButtons`. I have some other shapes, which are `Sprites`. On each type of elements have own type of listeners. I set active function buttons' `Stage` by `MENU` button.
It isn't practical, because newer devices haven't `MENU` button.

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if ((keycode == Keys.M) || (keycode == Keys.MENU)) {
       // some code
}
```

What do you think, how can I replace this "method"?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Because ImageButton uses touch/mouse click to activate, not a keyDown from an InputProcessor.

Comment: Why don't use just put a menu button on the GUI somewhere (e.g. in a corner), something like this: http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ICS-Screen05.jpg

Comment: @p.streef: There are already 2 different types of listeners. I can not use a button to change between listeners.

Comment: @gaRos: It is not standard android, so maybe hard to implement it.

Comment: @KovacsAkos If you would share your code with these 2 other listeners and explain what you want it to do maybe I can help, but this is just not enough information.

Comment: @KovacsAkos I know it's not standard android, but if you just create an Actor(with the menubutton texture) in the top right corner and implement its click listener, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with use of `InputMultiplexer`. It is really easy to use and do the trick. You should implement like this:

```
public InputMultiplexer(InputProcessor... processors)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information in your question.
But anyways there is a standard button creation:

```
// set the buttonStyle/load texture/etc.
ImageButton playButton = new ImageButton(buttonStyle);

// create a stage and add an actor
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.addActor(playButton);
//
// Now, set the input processor to this stage
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

// and add the clickListener to the button
playButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){/*override the down/up funcs*/});
```

After this, you can just link buttons to the new stages, set the inputproccessor, and this should work on new devices as well:

```
//create new stage
Stage stage1 = new Stage();
stage1.addActor(oldScreen.playButton);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage1);
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: There are already two different stages with different buttons.
I change between them inside keyDown function, like this:

                    `ExitButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(dialog);
                            pause();

                        }
                    });`

Default is inputController.